# Trouble with my program to filter a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please keep in mind that I am still fairly new to Python. I have this question which I have a fair bit of trouble understanding. I have made an attempt at this problem:

```
def Sample(A):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A == 1:
        print A
    elif A == (-1):
        print A
```

Question:

> Write a function where `A` is a list of strings, as of such print all the strings in `A` that start with `'-1'` or `'1'`

Comment: Try using more descriptive names for variables, like `listOfString` instead of `A`, and `string` instead of `i`. This will help you void getting mixed up, and help others read the code faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `if` and `elif` you are testing `A`, i.e. whether the *whole list* is equal to the value, which will never be `True`. Instead, test, each *item* in `A`. You can either stick with your index:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    if A[i] == ...
```

or, better, iterate over `A` directly:

```
for item in A:
    if item == ...
```

Next, to test whether a string starts with a character, use [`str.startswith`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```
for item in A:
    if item.startswith("1"):
       ...
```

Note that this uses the string `"1"`, rather than the integer `1`.

Comment: +1 This is exactly how a newbie should be explained with every details.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing if `A` equals `1` or `-1`, which is a bad start. You should be checking if **i** starts with either of those.

```
if i.startwith("1"):
```

**Edit:**
I completely edited my answer since I had misunderstood the question the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test for two cases does a_string in A start with '1' or start with -1.

Python offers a number ways to do this.  First, is the string.startswith('something') method.  This checks to see if the string startswith something you specified.

```
def Sample(A):
    for each_string in A:
        if each_string.startswith(('1','-1')):
            print each_string
```

Comment: This `print`s the whole list for each item!

Comment: `str.startswith` accepts a `tuple`, eg: `if each_string.startswith(('1', '-1')):`